# MKAnnotationView not working properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I'm trying to replace the MKAnnotationView image depending on an object value, the code is executed but the images are randomly assigned so they are not matched with the correct values.

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapview viewForAnnotation:(EventAnnotation *)annotation{

if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
    return nil;
static NSString* AnnotationIdentifier = @"AnnotationIdentifier";
MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [mapview dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier];

if(annotationView)
    return annotationView;
else
{
    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation
                                                                    reuseIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier];
    annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
    annotationView.image = [self setImageByType:annotation];
    annotationView.draggable = NO;

    return annotationView;
}
return nil;
}
```

setImageByType method:

```
- (UIImage*)setImageByType:(EventAnnotation *)annotation{
//Set annotation image depending on its type
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc]init];
NSString *type = annotation.type;

if ([type isEqualToString:@"event"]) {
    image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"geolocalization_events"];
}else if ([type isEqualToString:@"show"]){
    image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"geolocalization_shows"];
}else if ([type isEqualToString:@"culture"]){
    image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"geolocalization_culture"];
}else if ([type isEqualToString:@"eat"]){
    image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"geolocalization_eat"];
}else if ([type isEqualToString:@"drink"]){
    image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"geolocalization_drink"];
}else if ([type isEqualToString:@"cybercafe"]){
    image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"geolocalization_cybercafe"];
}

UIImage *finalImage = [self imageWithImage:image scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(50, 50)];

return finalImage;
}
```

resize the image:

```
- (UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize {
//Resize annotation image
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return newImage;
}
```

I would say the code is executed faster than the images are assigned to the views. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**

Try changing this line:

```
static NSString* AnnotationIdentifier = @"AnnotationIdentifier";
```

To this:

```
NSString* AnnotationIdentifier = annotation.type;
```

**Option 2**:

After this line:

```
MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [mapview dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier];
```

Add this line:

```
annotationView.image = [self setImageByType:annotation];
```

Comment: It seems to be working fine now! Could you briefly explain me why was that line the problem? (Worked with Option 1)

Comment: As I recall while using `UITableView`'s "dequeue" method, the object you get back isn't a new object. I haven't investigated fully, but basically it looks like the object could have the same property values as any other object used with that resuse identifier. Essentially, I had to completely reconfigure the object each time, setting all the properties to what they should be. If you only have to change a couple things, then I believe the performance is faster this way. In your case this is true since the `canShowCallout` and `draggable` don't need to be set.

Comment: The performance increase in your case is probably infintesimal, but the dequeue can be useful in other cases. Good strategy to use it though, I think.